# Where to install bash completion scripts for out of tree packages?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, autocomplete

I'm installing *ripgrep* on Ubuntu. It doesn't exist on the official repository or on private PPA's, so I'm following the project's instructions to install it as an out of tree package: https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep#installation.

I managed to learn that these packages should live on `/usr/local`:

- `/usr/local/bin` for binaries
- `/usr/local/share/doc/<package_name>` for documentation
- `/usr/local/share/man` for manual pages

What about bash completion? I understand that this is a little less standardized than those other categories and may be specific to each `Bash` installation. What is the way to do it in Ubuntu?

Comment: It appears to be installed in `/etc/bash_completion.d/`. Check `/etc/bash.bashrc` where that is loaded.

Comment: But then it would be mixed with apt controlled packages... I was hoping for a separate path.

Comment: What does "out-of-tree" mean here? Do you just mean not delivered by a package manager? It seems "out-of-tree" is a term specific to the Linux kernel

Comment: Yeah, I meant as outside of the distro's package manager repositories. I come from a Gentoo background where packages (ebuilds) are maintained in Git repos.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From what I could gather after a lot of reading, specially their [official documentation](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/master/README.md), `/usr/share/doc/bash-completion/README.Debian`, and the sources themselves:

- `/etc/bash_completion.d/` is the *legacy* dir, where completions are ***eagerly*** loaded, i.e., all sourced at once when the main script runs. Only a few packages still install there, most already migrated to the new standard.
- `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/` is the directory for completion files that are *dynamically loaded **on demand*** by `bash-completion`. They are only sourced *when* needed (and, most importantly, *if* needed), saving a ton of resources by not loading a bazillion completions for commands you'll never use.

---

Regarding this comment of yours about `/etc`:

> it would be mixed with apt controlled packages... I was hoping for a separate path

Files at `/etc` are not exactly "apt controlled", at least not in the same way `/usr/bin` or `/usr/share` are.<sup>**[1]**</sup> They are *configuration files*, and they are *meant* to be modified by the local admin (you). Packages create them at install time, usually containing the default values, and then you're supposed to modify them to your needs.

Some packages go one step further to ease maintenance and instead of (or alongside) config *files* they also create an (empty) configuration *directory* for "drop-in", extra customization files. So instead of *modifying* a config file to change some settings, a difficult and error prone task using tools like `grep`, `sed` and `awk`, you just *create* (or delete) "configuration snippet" files that override the desired settings.

Take a look at all `/etc/{,*/}*.d/` directories in your system. Does your package want to install a custom repository, like Google Chrome? Don't edit `/etc/apt/sources.list`, drop a file at `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. New services? `/etc/systemd/system/`. System settings? `/etc/sysctl.d/` (btw, see its README).

Much much easier, and no more stepping in each other's toes.

Some dirs in `/usr/share` behave like this too: your `.desktop` file go to `/usr/share/applications/`, and new mimetypes to `/usr/share/mime/packages/`, and so on. The difference to `/etc` is, you, the admin, are not supposed to neither *modify* nor *delete* files that you didn't create/installed yourself.

And that's exactly the case with `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/`.

---

That said, I have good news and bad news for you:

Bad news is... if you're tying to install the [completion in their github repository](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/blob/master/complete/_rg), that's not a bash completion, but a **`zsh`** completion file! And no, bash and zsh are *completely* incompatible regarding completions.

Don't worry, because the good news is: **[`ripgrep` is available on apt repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/ripgrep) since Ubuntu 18.10!** Yay! :D

```
sudo apt install ripgrep
```

And guess what? It contains a [bash completion file](https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/amd64/ripgrep/filelist)! Installed, of course, at `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/rg`.

Time to rejoice, pal!

---

<sup>**[1]**</sup>: To be honest, you could say they are "apt ***monitored***", not controlled. Read [Everything you need to know about conffiles: configuration files managed by dpkg](https://raphaelhertzog.com/2010/09/21/debian-conffile-configuration-file-managed-by-dpkg/) for more details.

Answer (score 8):

According to [FAQ manual](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion#faq), you should just put the completion file in the `~/.local/share/bash-completion/completions/` generally in the case your own local completions. If that directory doesn't exist, you can make it using `mkdir -p` of course.

> Put them in the **`completions`** subdir of `$BASH_COMPLETION_USER_DIR` (defaults to `$XDG_DATA_HOME/bash-completion` or **`~/.local/share/bash-completion`** if `$XDG_DATA_HOME` is not set) to have them loaded automatically on demand when the respective command is being completed.

The file's name is meaningful.

> The completion filename for **command `foo`** in this directory should be either **`foo`, or `foo.bash`**. (Underscore prefixed _foo works too, but is reserved for bash-completion internal use as a deprecation/fallback marker.)

Answer (score 2):

The distro completion scripts generally load user completions if found. E.g. on Ubuntu, `/etc/bash_completion` sources `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` .. and *that* sources scripts from `~/.ssh/..` and `~/.bash_completion` (which in my case sources `~/local/etc/bash_completion.d/*`).

So if you have your `~/.bash_completion` set up like that (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12426672/274318 for a way to source all files in a directory), you can just install the `ripgrep` completions to your local completions dir.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add that, although largely undocumented, scripts in `/usr/local/share/bash-completion/completions` are also loaded. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56389011/5637701). I also personally tested and verified with `RHEL8` and `Bash 4.4.20`.

Therefore if you are locally installing software in `/usr/local/bin`, this is probably where you want to place your completion scripts (as opposed to `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions`, which is managed by your package manager).

This directory probably doesn't exist by default, so just create it:

```bsh
mkdir -p /usr/local/share/bash-completion/completions
```

After putting your scripts in it and restarting your shell, your custom completions should work without needing extra configuration.